# discord.py: Leave a server

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make my bot leave a server when you run the command `leave`. At first, I tried to get my bot to kick itself but that didn't work, so I found here the method `client.leave_server` so I tried to use it but it's always giving the same error that Bot has no attribute leave_server. Does anyone know the right method?

My code:

```
import asyncio
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="+")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is ready")

@client.command()
@commands.is_owner()
async def leave(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Leaving the server!")
    await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
    await client.leave_server()

client.run("My_Token")
```

The error:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'leave_server'
```

Comment: There are a few errors in your code but to answer your question, you would use `await ctx.guild.leave()`.

Comment: It worked! Thank you for your answer but what errors are in the code?